# How to create multiple Laravel + Angular development environment

Tags: node.js, angular, laravel, development-environment

I'm part of multiple development teams with multiple projects and each project working with their own Angular and Laravel versions. The older ones mostly died on `ng build` because of different `node` or `node-sass` or etc versions.

I have a feeling about install and remove different versions is not the best way for working.

Is there any best practice, working solution, prebuilt virtula machines or anything else to handle this problem?

Comment: Looks like `nvm` is the way to go for you. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: I'm know about `nvm`, but this isn't solve the fundamentals of problem. The `node` is just only one thing in the environment.